# Slicing python list into sublists with values in certain ranges

Tags: python, slice

I'm looking for a way to slice a list into sections that contain values in set chunks. For example, I want to select values in a list called z_poisson that lie between 0 and z_max = 32

```
A = 2
z_max = 32
layers = 100
poisson = np.random.poisson(A,layers)

z_poisson = np.cumsum(poisson)
print(z_poisson)
[  3   7   8   8   8   9   9  13  14  16  18  18  21  25  30  32  33  33
  36  40  42  45  47  47  48  50  54  56  58  60  60  63  63  64  66  67
  70  70  71  74  81  82  84  85  87  89  93  95  98  99  99 101 103 105
 108 108 108 109 110 111 113 115 116 117 118 121 121 125 126 126 127 127
 128 129 135 135 137 137 139 141 141 144 147 149 151 156 158 160 163 164
 164 167 171 171 173 174 176 178 178 181]

#Sample steps of length z_max
first = [x for x in z_poisson if x < z_max]
print(first)
[3, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 13, 14, 16, 18, 18, 21, 25, 30, 32]
```

So it works correctly for one chunk, but I want to then create another list which will contain values between 32 and 64. In other words, I want to create vectors which have values which lie in 0 to z_max, z_max to 2*z_max, 2*z_max to 3*z_max, ... etc. Would appreciate help. Thanks

Comment: Look up `binning`; specifically, equal-width binning.

Comment: I would suggest writing out the full list comprehension for `z_max` to `2 * z_max`, `2 * z_max` to `3 * z_max`, etc., and then taking note of how they're similar to each other and how they're different from each other to see if you can write a function that will perform the splits you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result=[[x for x in l if x < z_max*(p+1) and x>z_max*(p)] for p in range(max(l)//z_max+1)]
```

This will give you a list of lists with elements that are between 0-32, 32-64, 64-96, etc.

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63], [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95], [97, 98, 99, 100,...